# Why can't find tensorflow>=1.9.0, after I have installed it? with Python Mac

Tags: python, tensorflow

try to install deepface and other packages, I found a problem:

```
"Searching for tensorflow>=1.9.0
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/tensorflow/
No local packages or working download links found for tensorflow>=1.9.0
error: Could not find suitable distribution for 
Requirement.parse('tensorflow>=1.9.0')"
```

I can import tensorflow in python3.9 and python3.10

and checked the python sys path include the tensorflow path :

tensorflow version 2.10.0
python  3.10.8 / 3.9.12. (install  two python, one is system (3.10.8), another is 3.9.12 install by pyenv)

Comment: Probably because the TensorFlow package for Mac is called tensorflow-macos, very bad idea for them to rename the package.

Comment: yes, it's bad idea to rename package,,, if it's the root cause, how can we do?